AdonisJS how to create 5.9.0 project?
Is it possible to create a new project based on the 5.9.0 Version of AdonisJS?
Preferably with the web-kit preset.
The documentation only tells me @lastest for the newest version or another option for the legacy 4.1 version.

Found it:
npx create-adonis-ts-app projectname

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
